# Extracting table using Htmlagilitypack + LINQ + Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, html-agility-pack

I'm having some difficulties using a lambda expression to parse an html table.

```
var cells = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                .SelectNodes("//table[@class='data stats']/tbody/tr")
                .Select(node => new { playerRank = node.InnerText.Trim()})
                .ToList();
            foreach (var cell in cells)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Rank: " + cell.playerRank);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
```

I'd like to continue to use the syntax as

```
.Select(node => new { playerRank = node.InnerText.Trim()
```

but for the other categories of the table such as player name, team, position etc.  I'm using Xpath, so I am unsure if its correct.

I'm having an issue finding out how to extract the link + player name from:

```
<a href="/ice/player.htm?id=8474564">Steven Stamkos</a>
```

The Xpath for it is:

```
//*[@id="fullPage"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a
```

Can anyone help out?

EDIT* added HTML page.
http://www.nhl.com/ice/playerstats.htm?navid=nav-sts-indiv#

Comment: Please provide the link to the page you are trying to scrape.

Comment: I have added the page I'm trying to scrape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
var result = (from row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='data stats']/tbody/tr")
                         select new
                         {
                             PlayerName = row.ChildNodes[1].InnerText.Trim(),
                             Team = row.ChildNodes[2].InnerText.Trim(),
                             Position = row.ChildNodes[3].InnerText.Trim()
                         }).ToList();
```

The `ChildNodes` property contains all the cells per row.  The index with determine which cell you get.

To get the url from the anchor tag contained in the player name cell:

```
var result = (from row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='data stats']/tbody/tr")
                          select new
                          {
                              PlayerName = row.ChildNodes[1].InnerText.Trim(),
                              PlayerUrl = row.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[0].Attributes["href"].Value,
                              Team = row.ChildNodes[2].InnerText.Trim(),
                              Position = row.ChildNodes[3].InnerText.Trim()
                          }).ToList();
```

The `Attributes` collection is a list of the attributes in an HTML element.  We are simply grabbing the value of href.

Comment: Is there anyway to get ""/ice/player.htm?id=8474564" from the link tag?  I can't figure it out.